# Clustered Annotations

Tags: objective-c, xcode, annotations, mkmapview

My app displays some locations on the map using annoations. The annotations also have a custom image and some important annotations are really close to each other which makes it hard to click them.
I remember Google Earth having some kind of implementation where annotations close to each other are bundled into 1 annotation and when clicked it showed the bundled annotations. I tried to do it again in Google Earth but it seems they removed that functionality.

However I'm looking for something like this so my annotations can be clicked even when they are close to each other. Can somebody push me in the right direction?

**EDIT**
Im also creating this for android and found this: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by hiding and showing annotations depending on span level:

```
if (mapView.region.span.latitudeDelta > 0.05) {
    // Zoomed out so show the clustered annotation
}
else {
    // enough zoomed in so the annotations wont overlap. Show the independent annotations
}
```